# Wordpress CSS — probably a very fix

Tags: html, css, wordpress, header, graphical-logo

I'm having problems with header (logo) on [my Wordpress site](http://www.fresherskitchen.co.uk).

Basically I want the logo to be above the navigation menu and then the navigation menu to be centered.

I've tried all sorts of different methods including margins etc. This is the code I have at the moment.

```
/*--HEADER MENU--*/
.userMenu {
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 30%;
    margin: -20px 0 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Please, give a meaningful title to the Question...

Comment: Please include enough HTML and CSS in your question to be able to replicate the issue. A link to your site is not enough to make this question valuable to future visitors, though a link to the problem in action is a useful companion

Comment: It's best practice to repeat the question at the end of the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around a little bit. The next actions should fix your problems.

- Delete `max-height` on `#header`
- Add `text-align: center;` on `#topBar`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#topBar #logo {
 color: #5B5B5B;
 display: block;
 font-size: 32px;
 line-height: 1em;
}

.userMenu {
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: bold;
 list-style: none outside none;
 text-align: center;
}
```